# Adding Speed Blur to Text

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, blur

I saw this sign on the Web and wanted to create a similar one using Photoshop. What would be the best way to take some regular, live text and add the speed/motion blur as seen on this image?

[image]

Comment: Set text, duplicate layer, add motion blur to lower layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps you can use to produce a similar result, some tweaking to taste may be necessary:

1. Create a blank document with a white background
2. Write the text you want in the color and weight you want
3. Press Ctrl-J to duplicate the layer
4. Pull the new layer below the original text layer (not terribly necessary but will make a neater stack)
5. Target the lower text copy layer
6. Go to Filter/Blur/Motion Blur
7. Keep the angle of the motion horizontal, at zero degrees
8. Move the blur slider to taste
9. Apply the filter, click OK
10. Optionally, lower the layer opacity to taste
11. Optionally, select the center part of the blurred layer leaving a thin top and bottom and delete the selected area

You should now have something like what I am adding below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked. The only other thing I had to do was move the bottom layer to the left a bit, making it look like the text is moving to the right while leaving a blur behind.